# BottomNavigationView with navgraph loading fragment again

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, androidx

I am using `BottomNavigationView` with `nav-graph`
Below is my code

In`MainActivity.class`

```
navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.mainFragment);

    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                navController.navigate(R.id.exploreFragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.events:
                navController.navigate(R.id.eventsFragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.stories:
                navController.navigate(R.id.storiesFragment);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_home"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color"
    android:background="@color/grey_50"
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

nav_home.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/exploreFragment"
    android:name="com.decathlon.allforsport.home.explore.ExploreFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_explore" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/eventsFragment"
    android:name="com.decathlon.allforsport.home.events.EventsFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_stories" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/storiesFragment"
    android:name="com.decathlon.allforsport.home.stories.StoriesFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_stories" />
```

So problem is when I tap on Home in BottomNavigationView, it reloads the fragment again and again. I tried many ways, but no success.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `navigation controller`, you can remove `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` function.

In `bottom_navigation` menu, **make sure** you define the item id same as the id you defined in `nav graph`.

And you need those code to make the bottom navigation bar works

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController!!)
bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController!!)
```

**Edit**

For androidx

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigation, 
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.mainFragment))
```

Comment: @Rohit use `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` instead of `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`

Comment: I am using andorid x.

Comment: I have used methid Hi,
I tried `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigation, navController);` 
It gave me same result. which is similar to  bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController) which is there for kotlin. 
It is calling onCreateView() of fragment again

Comment: Nope. :( Still searching for solution. So far I have got articles and answer for support but my code is in android x. `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` is in android x.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190077/discussion-between-rohit-and-john-joe).

Answer (score 0):

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.mainFragment) 
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
                if (it.itemId != bottomNavigation.selectedItemId)
                    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, navController)
                 true

}
```