# Room Data doesn't show in the RecyclerList

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-mvvm

It's first time using Room Data while also using MVVM pattern. The aim is that I want my data to appeard on the RecyclerList but it's doesn't shut down nor shows me any error it's just appears empty.

Here is my Database class:

```js
@Database(entities = [Plant::class, Plant_Category::class], version = 1)
abstract class PlantDatabase:RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun plantDao(): PlantOperations
    abstract fun plantCategoryDao(): PlantCategoryOperations

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: PlantDatabase? = null
             
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): PlantDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {

                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    PlantDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME // contains directory of sqlite database
                ) 
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
            }

            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    }
}
```

My dao class:

```js
@Dao
interface PlantOperations {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Plant")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<Plant>>

    @Insert
    fun insertPlant( plant: Plant)

    @Delete
    fun delete(plant:Plant)

    @Update
    fun updatePlant(plant:Plant)}
```

This is my repository class:

```
class PlantRepository(application:Application){
    private var allPlants = MutableLiveData<List<Plant>>()

    private val plantDAO = PlantDatabase.getDatabase(application).plantDao()

    init {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val plantData = plantDAO.getAll()
            plantData.collect{
                allPlants.postValue(it)
            }
        }
    }
    fun getAllPlants(): MutableLiveData<List<Plant>> {
        return allPlants
    }
    

}
```

My Viewmodel class:

```js
class PlantViewModel(
            application: Application
    ): AndroidViewModel(application) {

        private var repository = PlantRepository(application)

        private var _allPlants = repository.getAllPlants()

        val allPlants: MutableLiveData<List<Plant>>
            get() = _allPlants
    }
```

My Recycler in Fragment:

```js
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                               container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        lateinit var  photoAdapter: Photo_Adapter
        lateinit var plantViewModel: PlantViewModel

       
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit__form, container, false)
        val fab = view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton) as FloatingActionButton
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
          
      

        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
        photoAdapter = Photo_Adapter(context)
        recyclerView.adapter = photoAdapter

         plantViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(PlantViewModel::class.java)
        plantViewModel.allPlants.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
            photoAdapter.setDataList(it)
        })

       // photoAdapter.setDataList(dataList)
        //Floating button that opens the Form in order to add plant
        fab?.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(view.context, Edit_Form::class.java)
           startActivity(intent);
        }
        return view
    }
```

This is my adapter class:

```
class Photo_Adapter(var context: Context?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Photo_Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

        var dataList = emptyList<Plant>()

        internal fun setDataList(dataList: List<Plant>) {
            this.dataList = dataList
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Get the data model based on position
        var data = dataList[position]


        holder.title.text = data.name
        holder.desc.text = data.type.toString()


        holder.image.setImageResource(data.image)
        holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener { view -> //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"click on item: "+model.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            val intent = Intent(view.context, PlantDetails::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("plant_name", data.name)
            intent.putExtra("plant_image",data.image)
            intent.putExtra("plant_type", data.type.type)
            intent.putExtra("plant_water", data.type.water_time)
            intent.putExtra("plant_details", data.type.details)
            view.context.startActivity(intent)
    }

}
        // Provide a direct reference to each of the views with data items

        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            var image: ImageView
            var title: TextView
            var desc: TextView
            var relativeLayout: CardView

            init {
                image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image)
                title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
                desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc)
                relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.relativeLayout) as CardView
            }

        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Photo_Adapter.ViewHolder {

            // Inflate the custom layout
            var view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.photo_layout, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(view)
        }


        //  total count of items in the list
        override fun getItemCount() = dataList.size

}
```

Perhaps I forgot to add something? In Anyway I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: the `android-studio` tag is used when you ask a question about the IDE itself, doesn't seem like any answer you'll get here will depend on the IDE, so i've removed it from your post, no need to add it if you're not asking about the IDE

Answer (score 0):

You should not observe data on your repository, your activity/view should observe this data. Take a look at this:

First, add this dependency to your gradle:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
```

Then in your repository

```
class PlantRepository(application:Application){
     private val plantDAO = PlantDatabase.getDatabase(application).plantDao()
     fun getAllPlants(): Flow<List<Plant>> = plantDAO.getAll()
}
```

In your view model:

```
class PlantViewModel(
        application: Application
): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var repository = PlantRepository(application)
    val allPlants = repository.getAllPlants()
                   .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                   .asLiveData()
}
```

And your activity is fine, but check your adapter, make sure that you're notifing your adapter that your list has changed.
You can also work (collect) flows on your view, but this depends on you

Comment: I followed your advice and it didn't work I also added my adapter in the code.

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with the code, are you sure that you have data in your DB? If you set a breakpoint in the photoAdapter.setDataList(...) of your fragment it gets called?

Comment: I checked that I have data in Database I guess I will do a breakpoint

Comment: it's shows me that the the list size is 0 even though Database cointains  the data

Comment: So, something is wrong with your dao i can see that you're using Flow as return type, check that you have this 3 dependencies: implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"

Comment: It's has all three of them

Comment: If you want to you can check my github for the whole code : https://github.com/Editux/Plant_Management_App

Comment: I will be grateful if you check it

Comment: Your adapter is working fine, the problem is your navigation: As soon as i click the home item it displays a list of plants, but your navigation is not working. Even if i add new plants at the database the adapter displaysthe new items, you should configure your bottom navigation as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55178707/8276880 send me an email and I will explain you how to implement navigation :) nestorperez1396@gmail.com